# Preserve current selection on right click

Tags: javascript

I want to prevent the browser selection changing when the user right clicks on a particular div. I can capture the right click event on that div either with oncontextmenu or onmousedown and save the current browser selection, but even if I "re select it", it will be cleared (and the word I right clicked on will be selected) after the event listener is run.

How can I prevent a right click from changing the browser selection (or, how can I be notified after it changes so I can reselect the previous selection)?

(I don't want to put user-select: none on this div. Users should be able to select text in the div as normal, the issue is specifically with right clicks.)

Comment: Have you tried [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)?

Comment: Yes, that does not work.

Comment: Did you also try returning `false`?